# Reduce spacing between rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap grid system. The spacing between rows is too large.

How can I reduce it?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h1 id="Heading"> Heading </h1>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:6px;">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="rect"> <span id="Heading" style="margin-left:15px;font-weight:bold; font-size: 18pt;color: #2373B3;"> Span </span> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="rect"> <span id="Heading" style="margin-left:15px;font-weight:bold; font-size: 18pt;color: #2373B3;"> Span  </span> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="rect"> <span id="Heading" style="margin-left:15px;font-weight:bold; font-size: 18pt;color: #2373B3;"> Span  </span> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="rect"> <span id="Heading" style="margin-left:15px;font-weight:bold; font-size: 18pt;color: #2373B3;"> Span  </span> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Can you share the link or upload a demo? Not able to understand the problem properly...

Comment: There are multiple rows which i have created with bootstrap responsive grid. But the spacing between rows is too high i want to reduce the spacing. How can i reduce it, by decreasing the margin or by using some other methods.

Comment: Left & Right Paddings are there in the Grids, if you want to reduce the space, remove/reduce the padding...

Answer (score 11):

There are 2 quick solutions possible for this:

1. Edit bootstrap core css/sass which will be a bad idea as it will affect core functionality of page scaffolding.
2. Write a separate class and add it in your div for ex:

> .row-bottom-margin { margin-bottom:20px; }

and you can use it as

```
<div class="row row-bottom-margin">
```

Option 1 is not suggested until unless you are really looking for this change to be applied at all the relevant places and do consider your future designs.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Using Bootstrap 4 now you no more need to use any CSS for this as it has [utility classes for this purpose](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/).

Answer (score 1):

By default, row elements expands in related to their childs. So your problem is not in .row class but in #rect

On rect element you have a line-height of 1.4 by default bootstrap css. Make it a class rather than id.

You can reduce it to 1.2 for your case...
Do it on a separate css file and overwrite it. That would be a better design for you.

```
 .rect {        
    line-height: 1.2; // overwrite it on a different css if you prefer        
}
```

Comment: It should be #rect not .rect.

Answer (score 0):

In twitter bootstap there is a default margin-bottom:15px property set between rows of the grid system.You can remove this property or overwrite the margin property

```
    <div class= "row marginRow"></div>
Your Css    

  .marginRow{
   margin-bottom:0px !important; 
   }
```

or just remove any margin present using

```
    .marginRow{
     margin:0px !important; 
   }
```

Comment: try `margin-top` instead.